# Ubuntu 22.04 no longer recovering from suspend after kernel update

Tags: kernel, 22.04, suspend

Acer Aspire E5-573-70MD, received an upgrade from 6.5.0-25-generic to 6.5.0-26-generic, now will not resume from suspend.
On pressing a key to wake computer, instead of the regular tty1 login screen it shows a non-responsive screen in tty2. I have to go to another tty and reboot from there to get back to a login screen.
Also get an occasional message "Authentication is required to create a color-managed device", which is a new behaviour.

---

And after booting into the previous kernel a few times, then going back to 6.5.0-25-generic, the problem has gone away. Clearly, at my advanced age I am never going to understand how computers work, I'll just take the win and assume it was either voodoo or magic. 8-D